# Firebase Flashlight (ElasticSearch) filtering, sorting, pagination

Tags: node.js, search, elasticsearch, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using [Flashlight Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) plugin

I am using this [example](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/tree/master/example) and it's working fine

In the example you can see **[example.js](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/blob/master/example/example.js)** file have method for query as below

```
  // display search results
  function doSearch(index, type, query) {

      var ref = database.ref().child(PATH);
      var key = ref.child('request').push( { index: index, type: type, query: query }  ).key;
      ref.child('response/'+key).on('value', showResults);

  }
```

above function returning me the results when I pass values like following **JSON**

```
{ index: index, type: type, query: query }
```

It returning me nothing when i am trying to pass values like following **JSON**

```
{ index: index, type: type, query: { "from" : 1, "size" : 5 , "query": query }
```

but the following **ElasticSearch API** returning me the result

```
http://localhost:9200/firebase/user/_search?q=*mani*&pretty&size=5&from=1
```

and How do i filtering the query using Flashlight like following

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "drama"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            //Filter to apply to the query
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using following security rules

```
{
 "rules": {

  ".read": false,
  ".write": false,
  "search": {
     "request": {
        "$recid": {
           // I can only read records assigned to me
           ".read": "auth.id === data.child('id').val() || auth.uid === data.child('id').val()",
           // I can only write new records that don't exist yet
           ".write": "!data.exists() && (newData.child('id').val() === auth.id || newData.child('id').val() === auth.uid)",
           ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['query', 'index', 'type'])",
           "index": {
              // accepts arrays or strings
              ".validate": "(newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 1000) || newData.hasChildren()",
              "$child": {
                 ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 1000"
              }
           },
           "type": {
              // accepts arrays or strings
              ".validate": "(newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 1000) || newData.hasChildren()",
              "$child": {
                 ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 1000"
              }
           },
           "query": {
              // structure of the query object is pretty open-ended
              ".validate": "newData.isString() || newData.hasChildren()"
           },
           "$other": {
              ".validate": false
           }
        }
     },
     "response": {
        "$recid": {
           // I can only read/write records assigned to me
           ".read": "auth.id === data.child('id').val() || auth.uid === data.child('id').val()",
           ".write": "auth.id === data.child('id').val() || auth.uid === data.child('id').val()",
           // Assumes that Flashlight will be writing the records using a secret or a token that has admin: true
           // The only thing a logged in user needs to do is delete results after reading them
           ".validate": false
        }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Please let me know how to perform complex queries and filtering with Flashlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it myself

here is the solution

You need to update [SearchQueue.js](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/blob/master/lib/SearchQueue.js)

```
_process: function (snap) {
    var dat = snap.val();
    var key = snap.key;

    if (this._assertValidSearch(key, dat)) {

      // get your query string

    var q = dat.query.query;
    console.log('search', "test", JSON.stringify(dat, null, 2));
    // build your ES query
    //var q1 = {"query":{"match":{"_all":q}}};
        // Perform (a very simple) ElasticSearch query
        this.esc.search({
            index: dat.index,
            type: dat.type,
            // add options 
            from : dat.query.from,
            size : dat.query.size,
            // add ES Query
            //body : q1
            q:dat.query.query
        }, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                this._reply(key, {error: error, total: 0});
            } else {
                this._reply(key, response);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

and update [Example.js](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/blob/master/example/example.js)

```
   // display search results
   function doSearch(index, type, query) {
      var ref = database.ref().child(PATH);
      var jsonOBJ = { 
         index: index, 
         type: type, 
         query: { size:1, from:0, query:query},
      };
      var key = ref.child('request').push(jsonOBJ).key;
      console.log('search', key, JSON.stringify(jsonOBJ, null, 2));
     ref.child('response/'+key).on('value', showResults);
   }
```